# Getting the parameters such that the sum is close to 10^5

Tags: c++, vector

I need to get the values of two parameters a and b such that the sum is close as possible but less than 10^5.

I have written the code like this but can't seem to get the correct code for a and b.

Code:

```
vector<int> PointValue(vector<int> &bins)
{
    double sum = 0;
    vector<int> ValuesAnB;
    for(int a = 740; a < 750;a++)
    {
        for(int b = 130; b < 140; b++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(int x = 0; x < bins.size(); x++)
            {
                sum += pow(Exp(a,b,x),2.0);
                if(sum > 1e5)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ValuesAnB;
}
```

Instead of if(sum > 1e5) break, I need another statement that finds the values of a and b such that the sum is close as possible to 10^5 but above 10^5. Need some guidance in getting the correct values for a and b. Once I get the values for a and b, I can push it into ValuesAnB.

Comment: Why not: `a = 50000, b = 50000 - std::numeric_limits<double>::min();` and `a = 50000, b = 50000 + std::numeric_limits<double>::min();` ?

Comment: What do you want exactly a and b for sum less of 10^5 or above 10^5 or you want to programs one for that and one for the other?

Comment: want a and b less than 10^5. as close as possible..

Comment: what if it is exactly 10^5

Comment: less than 10^5. dun need equal to 10^5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't test it couldn't find Exp and don't have the values for bins.
But I think this code will pass.

```
vector<int> PointValue(vector<int> &bins)
{
    double sum = 0, result = -1;
    int finalA, finalB;
    vector<int> ValuesAnB;
    for(int a = 740; a < 750;a++)
    {
        for(int b = 130; b < 140; b++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(int x = 0; x < bins.size(); x++)
            {
                sum += pow(Exp(a,b,bins[x]),2.0);

                if(sum >= 1e5)
                    break;

                if (result == -1 || 1e5-sum < 1e5-result)
                {
                   result = sum;
                   finalA = a;
                   finalB = b;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (result!=-1) // if bins is empty there will be no results
    {
        ValuesAnB.push_back(finalA);
        ValuesAnB.push_back(finalB);
    }
    return ValuesAnB;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a problem in code. Exp(a,b,x) I think must be Exp(a,b,bins[x]) shall I modify it?

Comment: logic of your code seems wrong.. after it break, why place this:  if (result == -1 || 1e5-sum < 1e5-result)  below it?

Comment: The logic is not wrong. if it didn't break that means that sum is still less than 1e5 then we check if the new sum is closest to 1e5 than the old sum(result). if sum become larger than 1e5 it will break and sum will set to zero again (less than 1e5) and a new value of b will be taken to test with the bins values.